# Replace "?" with array data

Tags: php, pdo, bdd

I'm using a software that use PDO to do request. The database requests are like this :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM res_attachments WHERE res_id = ? AND status = ?";
$data = array('152', 'DEL');
```

The question I have is, how can I get the whole request with the "?" replace by $data elements ? I get this infos ($query and $data) after the query, I just have to "merge" it. I have to make a dynamic things, to works with a request with 2 arg or 10 args.

The result I want have to looks like :

```
"SELECT * FROM res_attachments WHERE res_id = '152' AND status = 'DEL'"
```

### Solution

For those who have a similar issue, here is the solution I make :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM res_attachments WHERE res_id = ? AND status = ?";
$data = array('152', 'DEL');
$tab = explode("?",$query);
for($i =0; $i < count($tab); $i++){
    $Request .= $tab[$i] . "'" . $data[$i] . "'";
    $finalRequest = str_replace('\'\'', '', $Request); // delete the double quote at the end
}
var_dump($finalRequest);
```

Comment: Read more http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php statement must be prepared to bind values to it. `query` is for execute an query without binding parameters. You will find that all in the docs.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Please edit and explain what you mean by "without the "?"" -- IOW, do you mean without the WHERE clause?

Comment: @SloanThrasher I've edited my question :)

Comment: I don't think the people who gave answers (so far) understood this question fully.

Comment: Yes @Fred-ii- , I've update my inital question to be as clear as I could

Comment: @Nathan30 I may not be able to help solve this but a question that does come to mind and may be relevant to what you're asking is: Will the number of entries in the array always remain the same, being two? You may want to re-edit it, if it stands to contain more items in the array. This looks more like auto-population from an array into multiple columns.

Comment: I re edit, to be more clear. Now I think it's okay ^^

Comment: Question updated with the solution I found :)

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is `prepare()` then execute rather than `query()`

`query()` runs a standard SQL statement and requires you to properly escape all data to avoid SQL Injections and other issues.

This is what you want :

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM res_attachments WHERE res_id = ? AND status = ?";
$data = array($res_id, $status);
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
if($stmt->execute($data)){
    //fetch your results

}
?>
```

or :

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM res_attachments WHERE res_id = :id AND status = :status";
$stmt  = $db->prepare($query);
if ($stmt->execute(array(
    ':id' => $res_id,
    ':status' => $status
))) {
    //fetch results
}

?>
```

**Update :**

> The result I want have to looks like :

```
    SELECT * FROM res_attachments WHERE res_id = '152' AND status = 'DEL'
```

You then simple use `debugDumpParams()` which dumps the information contained by a prepared statement directly on the output. It will provide the SQL query in use, the number of parameters used (Params),

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT * FROM res_attachments WHERE res_id = ? AND status = ?";
$data = array($res_id, $status);
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
if($stmt->execute($data)){
   $stmt->debugDumpParams();
}
?>
```

Comment: This is not really what I want. I've updated my initial question, maybe it wasn't clear enough :/

Comment: I re update my initial question, because I can't modify the execution of the query, I just get the request and the parametesr in an array

Comment: @Nathan30 updated my answer

Comment: Yes I see, thanks. But when I use the debugDumpParams() I have the number of arg, but not the value. And I can't use prepare and then execute. The request use query, I just have the string request and the array of parameters

Answer (score 1):

If $db in your code snippet is an instance of PDO, then you could use debugDumpParams() to see the SQL

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you, try this

```
 $sth = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM res_attachments WHERE res_id = ? AND status = ?');
    $sth->bindParam(1, $res_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->bindParam(2, $status, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->execute();
```

OR

```
$q = $db -> prepare('SELECT * FROM res_attachments WHERE res_id = ? AND status = ?');
$q->execute(array($res_id,$status));
```

Comment: This is not really what I want. I've updated my initial question, maybe it wasn't clear enough :/

Comment: WHAT ABOUT THIS?   $q = $db -> prepare('SELECT * FROM res_attachments WHERE res_id = ? AND status = ?');
$q->execute(array($res_id,$status));

Comment: I re update my initial question, because I can't modify the execution of the query, I just get the request and the parametesr in an array

Answer (score 1):

Try this, approach I used `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$index = -1;
echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/\?/',
    function () use ($data, &$index) {
        $index++;
        return "'{$data[$index]}'";
    },
    $query);
```